# adding multiple panels to a single panel/frame

Tags: java, swing

I am  making a 2d football game using swing. I have made different components in different classes. I am having trouble combining all these elements on a single panel , Hence I am not able to work all these components from a single class... Here is my code. Please help

```
//first class ball- which has ball physics


public class Ball extends JPanel{
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
public int x;
public int y;
public int vx=1;
public int vy=1;
Random a = new Random();
public Ball(){
    this.x=a.nextInt(500);
    this.y=a.nextInt(400);
}
private void physics(){
    x += vx;
    y += vy;
    if(x>(getWidth()-20)){
        vx*=-1;
    }
    if(y>(getHeight()-20)){
        vy*=-1;
    }
    if(x<0&&vx<0){
        vx*=-1;
    }
    if(y<0&&vy<0){
        vy*=-1;
    }
}
public void paint(Graphics g){
    super.paint(g);
    Graphics2D cicle = (Graphics2D) g;
    cicle.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
    Graphics2D bg = (Graphics2D) g;
    bg.setColor(new Color(114, 255, 72,255));
    bg.fillRect(0, 0,getWidth() , getHeight());
    cicle.setColor(new Color(206, 72, 255,255));
    cicle.fillOval(x, y, 20, 20);

    Thread temp = new Thread(){
        public void run(){
            physics();
            try {
                Thread.sleep(16);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            repaint();
        }
    };
    temp.start();
}
}
```

//second class player - which has vox moved by arrow keys

```
public class Team extends JPanel   implements ActionListener,KeyListener{
private Timer timer=new Timer(1,this);
private Attacker n=new Attacker(20,20,10);
public Team(){
    timer.start();
    setFocusable(true);
    addKeyListener(this);
    setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(false);
}
public void paint(Graphics g){
    super.paint(g);
    Graphics2D p = (Graphics2D) g;
    p.fillRect(n.getX(), n.getY(), n.getSide(), n.getSide());
    }
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    repaint();
}
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){
    int keycode = e.getKeyCode();
    if(keycode == KeyEvent.VK_UP){
        n.move(-1);
    }
    else if(keycode == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN){   
        n.move(1);
    }
}
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {}
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {}
}
```

// this is just players info

```
public class Attacker extends Player implements Observer,Shootball{
private int x;
private int y;
private int side;
public int getSide() {
    return side;
}
public void setSide(int side) {
    this.side = side;
}
public Attacker (int x,int y,int side){
    this.x=x;
    this.y=y;
    this.side=side;
}
public void shootball() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
public int getX() {
    return x;
}
public void setX(int x) {
    this.x = x;
}
public int getY() {
    return y;
}
public void setY(int y) {
    this.y = y;
}
public void move(int value){
    this.y+=value;
}
```

}

// code in Main Class

```
    public Foosball_Table()
    {
    setTitle("Background Color for JFrame");
    setSize(1000,600);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setVisible(true);
    setResizable(false);


    add(new ball());
    add(new Player());

    // Just for refresh :) Not optional!
    setSize(999,599);
    setSize(1000,600);
```

}

only a box shows up and nothing else

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Could you provide some more code? Like code from the ball of player?

Comment: [Laying Out Components Within a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html)

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example).

Comment: On some platforms there are differences between in the frame border for non-resizable and resizable frames.  Call `setResizable` BEFORE calling `setVisible`

Comment: What you seem to be doing is probably better done using custom painting. Have a look at [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) and [2D Graphics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/)

Answer (score 1):

Simple.. Use a `LayoutManager`.. for example `setLayout(new FlowLayout())` . for more refer https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html

```
public Foosball_Table()
{
    setTitle("Background Color for JFrame");
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setVisible(true);
    setResizable(false);
    setLayout(new FlowLayout())
    add(new ball());
    add(new Player());
    // Just for refresh :) Not optional!
    pack();
}
```

Comment: Or have him set x/y directly: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/none.html

Comment: even though we need setLayout(null).

Comment: No need for `setSize`, just use `pack`

Comment: @Joeblade  *"Or have him set x/y directly:"*  Do you have the ability and motivation to fix the next 10 problems that causes?  If not, please stop mentioning (bloody) `null` layouts.

Comment: Because clearly the layout managers do not cause any issues. I added it for completeness but I didn't post it as an answer as it's not the solution to this person's problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to start using `Layout`. There is a basic tutorial on Layouts right on `docs.oracle`: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html

In general, you have your different components (in this case, your Player and Ball, or even a background Field) in different panels that you combine together in a `Layout`. Usual choices are `FlowLayout` but you'll probably need a grid and work with the panels' absolute positioning. The tutorial covers this.

Also, spend some time doing tutorials of swing or JavaFX (a much more sensible and modern choice for your project) in general, as those two last code lines, the **"refresh"** as you called it, gave me glaucoma.

Answer (score 0):

Please provide more information about your classes `ball` and `Player`. It seems very likely, those classes are not composites and rather represent objects. Probably you will need to instantiate those classes as objects, such as

```
ball myBall = new ball();
Player myPlayer = new Player();
```

But we can only guess with the information you are currently providing.

Furthermore, Java class names should always start with a capital letter. I suggest to rename your `ball` class to `Ball`. You have to rename the code file to `Ball.java` then, too.